# In Angular2 when I am using an event emitter, the text in the select-box disappears

Tags: angular

I want to use ngModelChange and EventEmitter to do a specific task with the value in my select-box component. However as soon as I emit(), the text in the select-box disappears. The select-box works perfectly as soon as I remove the emitter Here is the complete code.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ContributorApi } from '../../../services/ContributorApi';
import { Contributor } from '../../../models/model.Contributor';

@Component({
  selector: 'module-builder-instructor-box',
  template: `
    <div class="inline-form-control-wrapper required-input-field margin-bottom-15">
      <select [ngModel]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" class="form-control medium-length gradient-bg font-medium">
        <option disabled> Select Instructor</option>
        <option *ngFor="let contributor of contributors"
          [ngValue]="contributor"
        >{{contributor.first_name}} {{contributor.last_name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  `
})
export default class ModuleBuilderInstructorSelect implements OnInit {
  @Input() instructorIndex: number;
  @Output() setInstructor = new EventEmitter<any>();
  contributors: Contributor[];
  selectedItem: Contributor;

  constructor(private contributorApi: ContributorApi) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contributorApi.getContributors().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.contributors = res;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  onChange(value: Contributor) {
    this.selectedItem = value;
    this.setInstructor.emit({index: this.instructorIndex, id: this.selectedItem.id});
    console.log(this.selectedItem);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show console logs when you change option on select? I'm not sure but _$event_ of ngModelChange is not Contributor object

Comment: $event can be any type of object. In this case it was a contributor object. Any ways I found the problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Actually this code is working fine

when you import this on parentComponent make sure you using a correct way to 
implement of EventEmiiter. for example

```
<module-builder-instructor-box (setInstructor)="ParentFuncName($event)"></module-builder-instructor-box>
```

and then on Parent.component.ts

```
 private  ParentFuncName(value: any) {
    // do your code here
    }
```

Comment: You were right it was working. I was actually making a change to the array used in the ngFor used to set number of selectbox components. This was causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a custom input component. A good practice for this is to implement ControlValueAccessor, so you can use [(ngModel)] when calling your component, and it integrates well with Angular Forms, and you can provide change callback from outside if needed :

```
<module-builder-instructor-box [(ngModel)]="myVariable" (change)="handleChange($event)"></module-builder-instructor-box>
```

Your component will look like this :

```
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

const noop = () => { };

@Component({
  selector: 'module-builder-instructor-box',
  template: `...`,
   providers: [
    {
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => FibaInputTextComponent),
        multi: true
    }
],
})
export default class ModuleBuilderInstructorSelect implements ControlValueAccessor {
    //The internal data model
    private innerValue: any = '';

    //Placeholders for the callbacks which are later providesd
    //by the Control Value Accessor
    private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
    private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;

    //get accessor
    get value(): any {
        return this.innerValue;
    };

    //set accessor including call the onchange callback
    set value(v: any) {

        // Put what you want to do when selected value changes here

        if (v !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = v;
            this.onChangeCallback(v);
        }
    }

    //Set touched on blur
    onBlur() {
        this.onTouchedCallback();
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    writeValue(value: any) {
        if (value !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = value;
        }
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.onChangeCallback = fn;
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
        this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
    }
}
```

Complete tutorial here: http://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel

Comment: Hmm that seems like a lot of extra stuff to add. It is working for me now anyways. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the problem. It had nothing to do with the emitter itself.
In the function that was being run by the emitter, I was changing the array used in the ngFor inside the parent component. This was resetting the child component hence resetting the selectbox.